# Why don't Software and Updates & add-apt-repository --remove delete PPA files?

Tags: ppa, add-apt-repository

I observe that removing a ppa with Software & Updates or with :

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xxx/yyy
```

merely empties the file one wants to remove and leaves an empty *theuglyppa.list* file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
(same with ppa-purge) Why is this ? This seem quite illogical to keep such residue especially for newbies who won't know that they should add :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/theuglyppa.list*
```

to their cleaning procedure. Where should this odd behaviour be reported as a bug ? As I consider this as a bug, unless somebody tells me what brilliant logic justifies such leftovers.

Comment: It may be that the removal of a PPA is a temporary expediancy on the part of the user - for example, I generally disable third-party PPA's prior to doing version upgrades in Ubuntu, then re-enable the PPAs

Comment: Well, that's when one unchecks the PPA in software-properties-gtk, this will comment the line, here it empties the file that one wants to remove, but doesn't actually remove it.

Comment: Just report it as a bug. If the devs don't consider it a bug, they'll close it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: To which team ?  I wasn't able to find if its apt, if there is a specific add-apt-repository team and if it was also to report to software-properties team !

Comment: @nam1962 see the linked question to determine which team to report to

Comment: Done : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1717522 (I'll check with ppa-purge team later if this team reacts)